# How to create a pause function when pressing a key

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am trying to invent a function that will pause a game when pressing <kbd>P</kbd>. I also want it to be shown on the screen while the game is running. However, I do not know how to continue my function. Also, is it possible to do this without using `import time`?

With my code, after starting the game, <kbd>P</kbd> only pauses one of the blocks and it never moves again.

```
def play():
    onkey(None,"space")
    clear()
    hanoi(6, t1, t2, t3)
    write("press STOP button to exit",
          align="center", font=("Courier", 16, "bold"))

def pause():
    onkey(None,"p")
    clear()
    hanoi(6, t1, t2 ,t3)
    write("Press P to Pause",
          align="center", font=("Courier", 16, "bold"))
    if onkeypress("p"):
        Pause = True

def main():
    global t1, t2, t3
    ht(); penup(); goto(0, -225)   # writer turtle
    t1 = Tower(-250)
    t2 = Tower(0)
    t3 = Tower(250)
    # make tower of 6 discs
    for i in range(6,0,-1):
        t1.push(Disc(i))
    # prepare spartanic user interface ;-)
    write("Aleksandar Stefanov's ToH. Press spacebar to start game",
          align="center", font=("Courier", 16, "bold"))
    onkey(play, "space")
    onkey(pause, "p")
    listen()
    return "EVENTLOOP"

if __name__=="__main__":
    msg = main()
    print(msg)
    mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just working through this and after getting something to work I simplified it down to this. It pauses a while loop by wrapping it contents in an if statement.

```
#screen.tracer is set to 0
#variable for if statement
PAUSED = False
#function to change variable
def pause_game():
    global PAUSED
    if PAUSED:
        PAUSED = False
    elif not PAUSED:
        PAUSED = True

#function tied to key press
screen.onkeypress(pause_game, "space")

#if statement I wrapped all content of while game_is_on loop
if not PAUSED:
     #(perform all function of game)
elif PAUSED:
    time.sleep(.01)
    screen.update()
```

C/P'd this code to my snake game and it worked the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep track of the game state to toggle it when you press <kbd>p</kbd>

Something like that :

```
def pause():
    if (GameStatus == 'play'):
         GameStatus = 'pause'
         #GAME IS ON PAUSE
    elif (GameStatus == 'pause'):
         GameStatus = 'play'
         #GAME IS ON PLAY

def main():
   global GameStatus
   GameStatus = 'play'
   onkey(pause, "p")
```

if you want to pause `onpress` and unpause `onrelease` you can use `onkeypress` and `onkeyrelease` to register your events

Something like that :

```
def pause():
    if (GameStatus == 'play'):
         GameStatus = 'pause'
         #GAME IS ON PAUSE

def unpause():
    if (GameStatus == 'pause'):
         GameStatus = 'play'
         #GAME IS ON PLAY

def main():
   global GameStatus
   GameStatus = 'play'
   onkeypress(pause, "p")
   onkeyrelease(unpause, "p")
```